# where is Socket.io 0.9.x document?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Because Some socket.io related client library are still support 0.9.x.  (eg: [Object-c library](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc), [Java library](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) )

So I need to read document about 0.9.x, so I try to visit

- http://socket.io/#how-to-use
- https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io
- https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events

This above link is about 1.x version. and the github wiki is not work.

Answer (score 12):

Socket.io still have parts of the documentation in their readme if you change to the 0.9.x tags/branch.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/0.9.17

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/tree/0.9.17

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But the readme seems missing some thing(not complete, the `authorization` is missing), I wanna to visit wiki page of 0.9.x

Comment: Authorization can be set with `io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback)`.

Comment: There's a github issue which has a similar answer: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1687